# borderlands 2 badass rank lost?? Can i mod a xbox 360 game save on xbox one?

Tags: borderlands-2

So if i play borderlands 2 xbox 360 version on my xbox one, can i still mod the game save or would i have to play it on the 360 to do so. Disclaimer not looking to break the game just looking to get my original bad ass rank and stats back. I have tried finding a save editor to do so, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

1. Modding your Xbox 360 Save
2. Load that save into your Xbox 360
3. Upload the character to the cloud
4. Load up BL2 on Xbox One
5. Retrieve cloud save

You can only have one cloud character saved at a time, so if you have multiple characters you have to switch back and forth after each upload.